Which of Kepler's laws would remain true if the force of gravity were proportional to the product of squares of each masses?
I was asked this question recently on which of the Kepler's Three law would remain if we changed the force of gravitation to be proportional to the product of squares of each masses instead of just product of the mass
I thought that the 2nd law was a result of conservation of angular momentum so it should be valid .
However I can't understand if the 1st and 3rd law will be valid or invalid .

The question seems quiet silly. But no, the 3.  law would not apply. you can easily check it for circular orbits.

The first law would still be valid.  The Binet equation can be used to show that any central force of the form $\vec{F} = -k/r^2 \hat{r}$ (with $k > 0$) will lead to orbits that are conic sections.
However, the third law would no longer hold;  the orbital period of a satellite will now depend on its mass as well as on the radius of its orbit.  This is pretty straightforward to show for circular orbits;  if $F = -k m^2 M^2/r^2 \hat{r}$, then we have
$$
m r \omega^2 = k m^2 M^2 / r^2 \quad \Rightarrow \quad \left( \frac{2 \pi}{T} \right)^2 = k M^2 \frac{m}{r^3}
$$
and so the square of the orbital period would be inversely proportional to the object's mass (as well as to the cube of the orbital radius.) More general orbits would have a similar dependence on mass.
